# Reading Buffer hex in meteor server

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm implementing a rest server on my meteor app, and I need to get one parameter from the request...

the problem is the parameter comes in this format:

```
data  <Buffer 74 65 78 74 3d 77 6f 72 64 73>
```

when i call

```
 curl -v 'http://localhost:3000/pagseguroNotifications' -d "text=words"
```

the buffer is the actual parameter but in hexadcimal...

how would i convert this to simple string in meteor?

my code is the following:

```
HTTP.methods({
  '/pagseguroNotifications': function(data) {
    this.setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    this.setStatusCode(200);

    console.log("data: ", data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buffers have a [`toString()`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end) method. Called without args, it converts the entire buffer to utf8 string.